# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "SwiftAudioEx"

Tags: swift, flutter

I am upgrade the [SwiftAudioEx](https://github.com/DoubleSymmetry/SwiftAudioEx) version to the newest version 0.14.5 in podspec like this:

```
s.dependency 'SwiftAudioEx', '~> 0.14.5'
```

when I build the flutter project, shows error:

```
Running "flutter pub get" in flutter-netease-music...           
Warning: You are using these overridden dependencies:
! flutter_secure_storage 4.2.1 (5.0.2 available)
Running "flutter pub get" in flutter-netease-music...            2,504ms
Analyzing dependencies
Adding spec repo `trunk` with CDN `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/`
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "SwiftAudioEx":
  In Podfile:
    music_player (from `.symlinks/plugins/music_player/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      SwiftAudioEx (~> 0.14.5)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `SwiftAudioEx (~> 0.14.5)`.
```

what should I do to fix this problem? Maybe the author did not publish this 0.14.5 version to the pod repo, could I use this 0.14.5 SwiftAudioEx version by the git url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the new 0.14.5 version did not upload to the pod repo, downgrade to the version 0.14.2 fix this problem.

Fix: finally I found the repo contains the version 0.14.5, but the web search UI only shows a lower version. I am using command in the terminal to search and install this component and success.

Comment: Same problem here when using react-native-track-player": "^2.1.2"
yarn install
[!] Unable to read the license file `LICENSE` for the spec `SwiftAudioEx (0.14.5)`

What can I do?

Comment: The version `0.14.5` was exists in the repo, I installed it using command line. @jr00n Try to install by command line. tring using `pod search` command, I have update my answer, if you solved this problem, please let me know.